# Upload array of files with thumbnail

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to upload multiple files from a single form but for some reason i get "The upload path does not appear to be valid." I have checked permissions and they are correct, so i dont know if this is a problem with the images it self.. these are the functions i use to create the images

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple id="img"></input>

function upload_image(){

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size'] = 2*1024;
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '1024';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('images'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        return $error;
    }   
    else
    {
        for($i = 0, $t = count($_FILES['images']); $i < $t; $i++) {

            $id = $this->files->create_thumb($i);

        }
    }
}

 function create_thumb($i){

    $file = $this->upload->data();
    $files = $file['file_name'];
    $fields = array('files' => $files[$i]);

    print_r($fields);
    exit;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'files/images/'.$files[$i];
    $config['new_image']    = 'files/images/thumbs/'.$files[$i];
    $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 120;
    $config['height']   = 120;

    $this->load->library('image_lib'); 
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();

    }

}
```

Comment: Well, try working on the path...Consider it's relative to the main index.php file, so you might try `./files/images..` for example

Comment: Add upload path to upload_image() function... Something like: $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH. '../files/images');, and initialize config, as mentioned in answer bellow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your config to `config/upload.php`. As an alternative solution, you can use the following line of code to initialize the config after loading the library:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

From the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called the upload.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file in: config/upload.php and it will be used automatically. You will NOT need to use the $this->upload->initialize function if you save your preferences in a config file.

To check if your directory is accessible by PHP, you can use [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/isdir):

```
var_dump(is_dir('/path/to/upload/folder/'));
```

Hope this helps!